# How to gridview will change index of rows using drag and drop

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `gridView`, which is movable, using drag and drop. `DragAndDrop` is moving rows of `gridView`, but unable to change the row index of `gridview`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0"  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333" runat="server">               
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnsave_Click" />
// js for dragAndDrop
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView2]").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
</Script>
```

This code only moves the position of row, but not row index of `gridView`.

I want the row index of `gridView` to change, when the save button is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this function code for for implementing drag and drop functionality.

```
$(function () {
    $("id*=GridView2]").sortable({
        items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        axis: 'y',
        dropOnEmpty: false,
        start: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.addClass("selected");
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.removeClass("selected");
        },
        receive: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
        }
    });
});
```